# Created a new empty project in XCode and added a View Controller but it wont compile

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Just like the title says, I created a new empty project in xcode that just gave me the AppDelegate header and compile files. I then added a view controller to it and then changed the Main Interface to the name of the viewcontroller xib file. I went ahead and ran the project without adding anything else. I've done this before and it has ran, but this time it is not.

The error message is

`'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 'setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'`

I have didn't write any code or changed anything other than what I explained above. The only code in the AppDelegate is the following:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PopOverViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.   
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface PopOverViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "PopOverViewController.h"

@interface PopOverViewController ()

@end

@implementation PopOverViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

I've searched through this site but couldn't find anything similar. Every post is about checking the IBOutlets and IBActions and connections but I havent done anything. All I did was like the View to the FileOwner, that's it.

Sorry if this is a repost/duplicate. If you find a page that is useful let me know.

EDIT: Also note that I did try to add the rootViewController (as shown below by Rob) but I still got the same error message.

Comment: You have cut off the start of that error message, and that generally tells us what class was sent the message.

Comment: @Rob: This is the full error message:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x85064a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x12b2012 0x10d7e7e 0x133afb1 0xdace41 0xd2e5f8 0xd2e0e7 0xd58b58 0x462019 0x10eb663 0x12ad45a 0x460b1c 0x4628da 0x24468b 0x2449a2 0x243876 0x254cb5 0x255beb 0x247698 0x24badf9 0x24baad0 0x1227bf5 0x1227962 0x1258bb6 0x1257f44 0x1257e1b 0x24317a 0x244ffc 0x5f9d 0x59a5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using NIBs, your app delegate would generally look something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[PopOverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopOverViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

If you create the app using the "Single View" application template versus the "Empty Application" template, you'll have an app delegate that has the appropriate code.

You generally don't have to supply the "Main Interface" field for your XIB unless you have a XIB for your window, too (not to be confused with your XIBs for the views for your view controllers). But XIB-based apps generally use the above `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` which eliminates the need for the "Main Interface" to specify a XIB for the window.

Comment: I actually tried that already and it didn't work. I copied and pasted your code just to double check but I still get this error:

` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x836e3a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.' `

Comment: here is the link to the repository of the project.

(https://github.com/cjjimenez/popuptest/tree/master/testPopUp)

Comment: @Chris I got the same error you did, but when I removed the "Main Interface", it worked fine. You don't need that because you're doing it programmatically in the app delegate.

Comment: [put biggest face palm in the world here!] OMG! Thank you so much! You rock and have been helpful! I thought I would have to do it programmatically as well as write it in the "main interface". Again thanks tons!

Comment: @Chris Don't sweat it. I think that old "Main interface" is unnecessarily confusing (I believe it's only used when specifying a NIB for the window, but now that NIB apps now do that in code, it's a bit redundant and definitely unclear).

Answer (score 0):

**'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 'setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'**

This issue usually appears when you change names to your .h .m files and do not update your .xib file.

Check in .xib file if there are any connection with invalid IBOutlet (right click on File's Owner and look for alert in the black box that appears).

Comment: I didn't add or change anything from any file. All I did was start and empty application and add a viewcontroller.h, viewcontroller.m and viewcontroller.xib. I also changed the Main Interface of the project to viewcontroller.xib. Ran it, then crashed. Changed the AppDelegate's didFishLaunchingWithOptions to make Viewcontroller to the rootviewcontroller. Ran it again, and it still crashed.

Comment: @downvoter Please, explain the reason of your downvote, when downvoting. What I've written above it is actually correct. The error reported is usually connected with wrong connection, and it is possible that wrong connection happens...

Comment: "I also changed the Main Interface of the project to viewcontroller.xib." This is wrong!! Remove anything you put in Main Interface and leave it blank as @Rob suggested.

Comment: Yeah I did that. Thanks! I didn't know it had to be empty.